# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054 Codeigniter Unknown column ' order_discount' in 'field list'

Tags: codeigniter-2

A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column ' order_discount' in 'field list'

```
INSERT INTO `vendor_order_relation`(`vendor_id`, `order_id`, `order_date`,`cart_order_value`,`vendor_discount`,`payout`, `order_value`, `discount_price`,` order_discount`) SELECT `vendor_id`,'89','2017-11-10',`cart_order_value`,`vendor_discount`,`payout`, `order_value`, `discount_price`,` order_discount` FROM `vendor_order_relation` WHERE `order_id` ='85'
```

Filename: `controllers/Checkout.php`

Line Number: 121

Comment: can you try explaining the code again, is it that you are trying to insert into vendor_order_relation by means of a select statement from the same table

Comment: Check your table column name `order_discount` is available or not and remove space `order_discount`

Comment: @SuneelKumar you sure space will matter?

Comment: @Satya Yes, check the query once put a space before column.

Comment: Thank you solve the error. You are right, Space is Matter.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Does the order_discount field exists in the database table.
2. Check the spelling of the field , does it matches with the database.